# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] this question is already existed but still I am not able to find it out

Tags: node.js

admin.js and products.js is given below respectively

```
const express=require('express');
const path=require('path');
const router=express.Router();
const productsController=require('../controllers/products.js');
router.get('/addproduct',productsController.getAddproduct);
router.post('/addproduct',productsController.postAddProduct);
module.exports=router;
```

```
const products=[];

exports.getAddproduct=(req,res,next) => {
   res.render('add-product.ejs', {
      pageTitle:'Add product',
      path:'/admin/addproduct',
      prods:products
   });
};

exports.postAddproduct=(req,res,next )=> {
   products.push({ title:req.body.title });
   res.redirect('/');
};

exports.getproducts=(req,res,next) => {
   res.render('shop.ejs', {
      prods:products,
      pageTitle:'shop',
      path:'/'
   });
};
```

Above code is the product.js code snippet 
I am not able to find the error in the above code snippet

Comment: Can you show the contents of products.js file also?

Comment: 'const products=[];

exports.getAddproduct=(req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('add-product.ejs',{
        pageTitle:'Add product',
        path:'/admin/addproduct',
        prods:products
    });
};

exports.postAddproduct=(req,res,next)=>{
    products.push({ title:req.body.title });
    res.redirect('/');
};

exports.getproducts=(req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('shop.ejs',{
        prods:products,
        pageTitle:'shop',
        path:'/'
    });
};'

Comment: Edit your original question and include it over there please.

Comment: ya corrected now

Comment: `postAddProduct` in admin.js does not match `postAddproduct` in products.js